# Tooltips over a treeview

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application that has a page with a treeview whose treeview items have multiple columns containing different kinds of UI elements.  Rather than making a tooltip for each element in each treeview item, I want to make a generic tooltip for each column.  This will prevent the user from having tooltips popping up all the time as they move their mouse over all the elements in the treeview.  A sample of the application page can be seen here.

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BAWW.jpg)
I have tried a number of ways to do this and am looking for anyone's good idea.  At present, I have added transparent borders over the top of the treeview border and attached tooltips to them.  This does not work because a transparent element won't capture the hit test to enable the tooltip.  However, if I make the border background anything but transparent, the border will capture the hit test, show the tooltip, and the underlying controls won't work.

I know many posts here are answered by "Why would you want to do that?"  As a courtesy, I would appreciate ideas to accomplish my goal rather than reasons why I should not try it.

The xaml I am showing has a reusable custom tooltip user control that allows me to supply a key that finds the language, text and images used on the tooltip for the related element.  That works fine and is not a part of this issue.  Thanks folks.

```
 <!--Tree view border-->
<Border x:Name="tnk_TreeBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="22,-2,26,2"
        CornerRadius="6" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBorderBrush}"
        Background="{DynamicResource MyPopupBackgroundBrush}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="280" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="326" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="46" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ctls:MyTreeView x:Name="tnk_TreeView" Style="{StaticResource MyTreeViewStyle}" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TreeNodes}"
            HighlightSelected="False" Margin="2,2,2,2"
            Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <ctls:MyTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemStyle}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseEnter" />
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseLeave" />
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDown" />
                    <EventSetter Event="Expanded" Handler="TreeViewItem_Expanded" />
                </Style>
            </ctls:MyTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <TreeView.ItemTemplate >
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                    <Grid Height="45">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="260" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ItemName}" Margin="6,6,0,0" 
                               Foreground="{DynamicResource MyTextBrush}"/>
                        <views:GaugeView Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,0,10" 
                            LeftText="{Binding MinText}" RightText="{Binding MaxText}" 
                            Percent="{Binding Percent}" Color="{Binding Color}"
                            Orientation="LeftToRight"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="2"  Height="26" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                            <Border Height="26" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" 
                            CornerRadius="4" Background="{DynamicResource MyDataLabelBackgroundBrush}" >
                                <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,0">
                                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding DisplayValue}" TextAlignment="Right" 
                                  Foreground="{DynamicResource MyTextBrush}" Margin="2,-2,2,0" />
                                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding UoM}" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Left" 
                                  Foreground="GhostWhite" Margin="2,4,2,0" />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ctls:MyBasicButton ButtonName="tnk.btn_Value" 
                            Style="{StaticResource MyInvisibleButtonStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,0"               
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            CollectionKey="{Binding Key}"
                            Command="{Binding ButtonPressedCommand, Source={StaticResource viewmodelbase}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="3">
                            <ctls:MyBasicButton ButtonName="tnk.btn_Dampen" 
                            Style="{StaticResource MyImageOnlyButtonStyle}"
                            Margin="10,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                            CollectionKey="{Binding Key}"
                            Image="{Binding DampenImage, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}" 
                            MaxImageSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Command="{Binding ButtonPressedCommand, Source={StaticResource viewmodelbase}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>

                            <ctls:MyBasicButton ButtonName="tnk.btn_Valve" Style="{StaticResource MyInvisibleButtonStyle}" 
                            CollectionKey="{Binding Key}" Margin="10,-2,0,0" Width="38" Height="25"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Visibility="{Binding ValveIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                            Command="{Binding ButtonPressedCommand, Source={StaticResource viewmodelbase}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                <ContentControl Style="{Binding ValveNumber, Converter={StaticResource IntToValveConverter}}" />
                            </ctls:MyBasicButton>

                            <ctls:MyBasicButton ButtonName="tnk.btn_Transfer" Style="{StaticResource MyLEDButtonStyle}" 
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBorderBrush}"
                            CollectionKey="{Binding Key}" Margin="38,0,0,0"
                            Background="{Binding LEDBrushNumber, Converter={StaticResource IntToLEDBrushConverter}}"   
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Visibility="{Binding LEDIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                            Command="{Binding ButtonPressedCommand, Source={StaticResource viewmodelbase}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </ctls:MyTreeView>
        <!--Borders for tooltips-->
        <Border Grid.Column="0" 
                ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="2000"
                ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="0"
                ToolTipService.ShowDuration="60000"
                ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
            <Border.ToolTip >
                <ctls:MyHelpTip Style="{StaticResource MyHelpTipStyle}"  
                    Visibility="{Binding ShowHelpTips, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <views:HelpTipView DataContext="{StaticResource HelpTipViewModel}" ControlID="tnk_Names" />
                </ctls:MyHelpTip>
            </Border.ToolTip>
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" Opacity=".2"
                ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="2000"
                ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="0"
                ToolTipService.ShowDuration="60000"
                ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
            <Border.ToolTip >
                <ctls:MyHelpTip Style="{StaticResource MyHelpTipStyle}"  
                    Visibility="{Binding ShowHelpTips, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <views:HelpTipView DataContext="{StaticResource HelpTipViewModel}" ControlID="tnk_Gauges" />
                </ctls:MyHelpTip>
            </Border.ToolTip>
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" />
        </Border>
        <!--Background colors here are for screenshot only-->
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="PaleVioletRed" Opacity=".2">
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="3" Background="CornflowerBlue" Opacity=".2">
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" />
        </Border>
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" />
        <Border Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,0,20,0" Background="SeaGreen" Opacity=".2">
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Maybe, have a button/link with `?` at the top right of each column and then when the user hover over, you can display tooltip or even a popup on clicking on that button. Just an alternative.

Comment: vesan,  I appreciate the suggestion.  I have about thirty other pages in my app and nowhere do I use a button or icon to activate a tooltip.  Your idea would violate the consistency of my user experience rules.  Also, if I put a little element in the column, I am still back to the same problem of the underlying treeview items not firing any interaction events.  Thanks for the idea.